# Shannon theorem and equation Eb/N0

Tags: network

Understand that Eb/N0 is based on (S/R)/(N/B)

S = signal power (W) R = bit rate (bps) N = noise power (W) B = bandwidth (Hz)

How can I solve this equation if I only have these values: (SN/dB): 40 dB Bandwidth: 700 000 Hz Effective data rate: 80% of maximum channel capacity.

[EDIT with my working]
I have work out the equation as follow: Eb/N0 is also = (S/N)*(B/R) therefore Eb/No = 40 * (700,000/7 759 462.4) = 3.61 (2 decimal places) 3 questions: 1) Is my answer correct? 2) Is there a unit for this? 3) What is the correct way to convert a Mbps to bps? For the above answer, I used Google for conversion.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you show us what you have tried? How much _do_ you understand about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the data rate from Shannon's channel capacity equation since the SNR and the bandwidth are known.  Applying these values yields a maximum channel capacity of 9.3 Mbits/second.  Since your effective data rate is specified as 80% of that, your data rate is 7.4 Mbits/sec. Now you have all the values for your equation: S/N = 40 dB, R = 7.4 Mbits/sec and B = 700,000 Hz.

Comment: I have work out the equation as follow:
Eb/N0 is also = (S/N)*(B/R)
therefore
Eb/No = 40 * (700,000/7 759 462.4) = 3.61 (2 decimal places)

3 questions:
1) Is my answer correct?
2) Is there a unit for this?
3) What is the correct way to convert a Mbps to bps? For the above answer, I used Google for conversion.

Comment: Hi Barry, hope to hear from you soon.